# Overvoltage shut down

Tags: mosfet, spi, protection, display

A LCD display controller includes a 5 times DCDC converter. A circuit is needed to ensure that the in case of a fault in the display the 5 times voltage can not return to the CPU circuit in anyway.
The interface to the display will be +3.3V, GND and a (one way) SPI.
We have a solution with a Schottky diode, but could it be done in a smarter way with a fet?
[image]

Comment: What's the tolerance on your shutdown voltage?  Big difference between 1% and 10% in so far as circuit complexity goes.  You might want to consider using an analog comparator to sense the voltage, then use its output to drive the FET.

Comment: Vin will normally be between  0-3.6V and the maximum accepted return voltage will be 4V, the reason for not just using a zenerdiode is because a Vmax 4.0V Zenerdiode will use current especially at in the low voltage region. It is a low power application. So the tolerance could be from 3.6 to 4.0 V